# How to transform the excel file which doesn't have the column header in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am getting one excel file every day in the data lake. My requirement is to export the excel file into an SQL database using ADF. I have five sheets in the excel file. Among the five, I have one excel sheet that doesn't have one column header. I successfully exported all four sheets into the SQL database.

I stuck with the above one sheet which doesn't have a column header. Below is the data for this excel sheet
[image]

See, the first column doesn't have a header. When I tried to use copy activity, the schema is neglecting the first column as it doesn't have a header. When I untick the first row as a header, then it's recognised. However, I don't want to use this because the column header for other columns considers a row value which is difficult as everyday new excel file is getting added.

Any advice on how to address this issue? Tried a lot, with no success.

Comment: If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Comment: Thank you very much @AbhishekKhandave-MT. I tried to follow up on your step using data flow but had no success. I am sure I am doing something wrong. In step 1: Excel as a source, did you select the "File row as a header"? When I tried to select the file row as a header, then I am not getting the first column in the projection. When I untick the "file row as a header" then I can get it but I am getting an extra row in the data with file headers. Could you please advise?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this issue. But initially I got below error.

> ErrorCode=DelimitedTextColumnNameNotAllowNull,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The
> name of column index 1 is empty. Make sure column name is properly
> specified in the header row.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'

[image]

**Source File:**

[image]

So I used DataFlow activity and resolved the issue.

Follow below steps.

**Step1:** Select Excel as Source.

[image]

[image]

**Step2:** Select transformation settings.

[image]

**Step3:** Execute Pipeline.

Data stored in SQL DB.

[image]